# Retain filtered list before applying another filter using ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list called `ListA`. I am performing some filters on it and saving in a new array called `filteredList`.

```
<div ng-repeat="element in filteredList =(ListA| filter: {label:searchCategory.value} |filter:searchString)">
```

NOW, I want to use the `filteredList` to implement pagination. I have already implemented pagination for another page using `splice(start, end)` where I update the `start` and `end` values to update the visible array.
Adding splice to filter will change my `filteredList` size, which I need in order to calculate the number of pages for pagination.

What I would need to go into `ng-repeat` would be something like this

```
ng-repeat="element in newList.splice(start, end)" where `newList` without splice is essentially `filteredList`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, what you would need is to filter the List in the Javascript itself.

For your scenario

In your controller:

```
var ListA = [<some-data>];

$scope.filteredList = $filter('filter')(ListA, searchString );
$scope.filteredList = $filter('filter')($scope.filteredList, {label:searchCategory.value} );
```

You should use the Filter values on click of some event and recalculate this filteredList on the handler.

If the items are less than 200 then you can implement live filtering by implementing a watcher on the filter expressions.

Comment: Perfect! I put this in a function and called on model change. Minor changes though. I have updated the answer. Thanks!